# KeyPress function in Android

Tags: javascript, android, dom-events

I have a little problem.
I am using this function in my JavaScript. The function is working good in all browser on my pc.
But it's not working in my Android tablet. Can anyone tell what can be the issue? Below is the function:

```
function keypress(e,obj) {
    getCodeVal(e,keyCode,obj);
    document.myMain.txtRequest.value="123";
    obj.value="444";
}
```

```
<INPUT id=txtRequest onkeydown="return keypress(event, this)" 
 onkeyup="keyup(event, this)" onpaste="return false;" maxLength=21 name=request>
```

Comment: "it's not working" means what?

Comment: function not responding.

Answer (score 0):

I guess onkeypress event is not at all firing !!
try binding 'input' event instead of on keypress

```
inputElement.addEventListener("input", keypress)
```

and you may need to modify keypress function code.